# Can we adjust the $e$ limit to go to 1?

Tags: calculus, eulers-number-e

We know that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e
$$
and
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\frac{1}{e}
$$

My question is: Are there any non-trivial:

- $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ monotonic non-decreasing
- $g:\mathbb{N}\to[-1,1]$

such that:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+g(n)\right)^{f(n)}=1
$$
It seems to me that except for the case where there exists an $N>0$ such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $g(n)=0$ - there are no other $f, g$ satisfying this limit.

Thank you.

Comment: In general if $g(n)f(n)\to 0$ then it converges to $1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What's the argument for that? I can see it easily if $g=o(1)$, but...

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it also requires  $g(n)\to 0,$ I guess. I was s already sort of mentally assuming $f(n)\to\infty.$ Then $\ln(1+g(n))=g(n)+o(g(n))$ so $f(n)\ln(1+g(n))=f(n)g(n)+o(f)n)g(n))\to 0.$  @Milten

Answer (score 3):

Let $g(n)=1/n^2$, $f(n)=n$. Then $$(1+g(n))^{f(n)}=\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^n=1+n\cdot\frac1{n^2}+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\frac{1}{n^4}+\cdots\to 1.$$
In general, it suffices to have $g(n)$ going to zero sufficiently rapidly as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes, you need $g(n)f(n)\to 0.$